# Objective C UIViewController property with a default value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` (iOS) with a bool property set from the view that created it.

Can I have a default value for a property?

If I put it in `ViewDidLoad` it will get called even if I set the value to something different before pushing the `ViewController`

Some code to @Erakk's request to figure out the problem:

@implementation CreateMomentViewController

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
    // NOT GETTING EXECUTED
    CreateMomentViewController *me = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    me.exitButton = YES;
    return me;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    self.exitButton = YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The caller:

`ChefSelectionViewController` is a sub-class of `CreateMomentViewController`

```
ChefSelectionViewController *nextScreen = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChefSelect"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextScreen animated:YES];
});
```

Comment: Putting in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad won't fix the issue. The correct way to do this is to override the initializers, like in @Luke's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your initWithNibName to this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        self.exitButton = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, i dont think you would need a subclass of a viewController just to create it, but i don't know how your flow works so it's just a comment =)

By the way, the view you are instantiating by the name of `@"ChefSelect"`, it's class (in the xib / interface builder) should be the same as `CreateMomentViewController`. It could happen that you are actually instantiating `ChefSelectionViewController` and your code on `CreateMomentsViewController` would never be called.

Comment: while your way of initializing is not wrong, this is how apple recommends.

Comment: wait... I lost you ChefSelectionViewController is-a CreateMomentViewController
`@interface ChefSelectionViewController : CreateMomentViewController` doesn't the default `initWithNibName` calls super's one?

Comment: I mean on the interface builder.

In code you are correct. Check the .xib class on the *interface builder*.
Even if everything is correct, if the class you set on the .xib is of type `ChefSelectionViewController`, the code you put on `CreateMomentViewController` will never be called. If you still didn't understand i just ask =)

Comment: Also, i updated my answer. Apparently, from interfaceBuilder files, it uses initWithCoder instead of initWithNibName. i was wrong there =)

Answer (score 3):

I follow this standard for setting default values.

```
- (void)customInit {
    // Default Values
    self.exitButton = NO;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}
...
...
```

Comment: When you instantiate a viewController from a storyboard, initWithCoder is called since  the viewController is itself serialized into the compiled storyboard. Basically, your viewController is rehydrated from an NSKeyedArchive. Rather than overriding init, though, you should override `initWithNibName:bundle:` and `initWithCoder:`. Those are pretty much the only two initializers that you ever need to override for a `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: I don't think the base `init` method is called for the ViewControllers within any of my apps but I do use this same `#pragma mark - Initialization` sections within most of my subclasses. I leave this init method here because it has become a standard of mine to include all of the available init methods with calls to the `customInit` if I have one.

Comment: The base init actually calls `initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I would override `-initWithNibName:bundle:` and put it in there. Default values belong in initializers. Make sure you call `[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]`.

Comment: Your answer, while correct, assumes he is using .xib.
Even if he is, i would edit this question with a non .xib example too =)

Comment: @Erakk - Just wanted to ask... it is not working because it is a storyboard ViewController. What is the variant in this case?

Comment: @Boaz - Luke's answer should be working. in this case posting some code (like where you set the property and where you initialize it on the viewController) could help.

Other initializers you can use is `-init` and `-initWithFrame:` but when you initialize a viewController from th.xib/interface builder, it calls `-initWithNibName:`

Comment: Hmm, isn't initWithNibName:bundle: the only designated initializer for UIViewController?

Comment: If you are working with xib, yes. if interface builder, it does some extra things so it uses `-initWithCoder`